# Converting JSON to class

Tags: java, json, jackson

and a class named Entry.
How can I convert the GlossEntry Object in json to an Entry Class Object in java.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the ["Jackson in 5 minutes" page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example), which takes 5 minutes to read:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
Entry entry = mapper.readValue(new File("entry.json"), Entry.class);
```

EDIT: sorry, I misunderstoof your question. If you want to read a sub-tree of the JSON into a Java object, then [read the full JSON as a Tree](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel), then get the sub-tree from the root node, and use `ObjectMapper.treeToValue()` to transform the sub tree to an Entry Java object. All the steps are described in the page I linked to.

Comment: But then i have to map the whole json file to a class which I want to avoid.I just want to map GlossEntry

Answer (score 0):

It depends on platform you are using for the converting; For example using Gson from google needs just tow lines of code, the following example shows how get campaign obj from this json

```
    String rsou = "{\"name\":\"name\",\"startDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:30\",\"endDate        \":\"01/03*d/2013 12:30\",\"variable\":\"\"}";

    Campaign newCampaign = new Gson().fromJson(rsou, Campaign.class);
```

Comment: The OP explicitely asked about Jackson, not GSon.

Answer (score 0):

[JSONClass](http://www.jsonclass.com)
describe service interfaces, auto generate class files, 
support C++, C#, Java, Objective-C, Python, Go.

Comment: 404 page not found